# Can not write in later added sortable input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `<table id="table">` inside the table are input fields that needs to be sortable. With a button you can add new inputfields. Unfortunately in the later added input fields can not be written.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution.

Can you give me tips or help me?

I have the Problem in FireFox 15.0.1

Comment: can you share code or create a jsfiddle.net of it so we can see it in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `.disableSelection()` if you remove it then text is editable.

Comment: The solution: $("#table tbody").sortable(); instead of $("#table tbody").sortable().disableSelection();